# How to add cluster module of NodeJS to my meteor@2.0.0 project?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

How to add cluster module of NodeJS to my meteor@2.0.0 project? Any kind of suggestions that will help to scale up my application are appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.